# Dealing with select lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, selectlist

I got a model defined as `IEnumerable<MyViewModel>` which I tried to use to create a select list (`Html.SelectListFor`). But I couldn't figure out how to do it. Which made me look at the plain `Html.SelectList` method.

Since it wants a `IEnumerable<SelectListITem>` and I don't want to add view specific logic in my controller or logic in my view I ended up to create the following extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, string> valueSelector, Func<T, string> textSelector)
    {
        return items.Select(item => new SelectListItem
                                        {
                                            Text = textSelector(item),
                                            Value = valueSelector(item)
                                        }).ToList();
    }

}
```

Which I use as:

```
@Html.DropDownList("trainid", Model.ToSelectList(item => item.Id, item => item.Name));
```

This doesn't seem to be the optimal solution. How should I have done?

Comment: That seems like a very good generic solution to build select lists

Comment: It works, but there must be a more straight forward way to do it with MVC? If not, what is the intended purpose for `Html.SelectListFor`?

Comment: " don't want to add view specific logic in my controller " - Wait, isn't this the primary responsibility of the controller?  Assemble data for the view?

Comment: Assemble data yes. But generating a select list / html? imho that's very view specific.

Comment: I agree with hunter, what's wrong with it?  "If it's stupid but it works, it ain't stupid".  I got something very close to that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess that the answer is that I'm already using the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

jg,

funnily enogh, I must have sourced a similar article when looking for a solution like this. i've got an extn method that goes:

```
public static IList<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> list, 
    Func<T, string> textSelector, 
    Func<T, string> valueSelector, T selected) where T : class
{
    var results = new List<SelectListItem>();
    if (list != null)
    {
        results.AddRange(
            list.Select(item => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = textSelector.Invoke(item), 
                Value = valueSelector.Invoke(item), 
                Selected = selected != null ? selected.Equals(item) : false
            }));
    }
     return results;
}
```

and is invoked as:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("Base.EntityRootID", Model.EntityRootList.ToSelectItemList(foo => foo.EntityName, foo => foo.ID.ToString(), Model.Base.EntityRoot))%>
```

how weird. i actually like this method as it's both generic and by using the entity itself to compare the selected item with, means that you don't ar$e around with comparing id's etc..

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I really like this approach.  I made one change to add a selected item parameter.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, string> value, Func<T, string> text, object selectedValue)
    {
        return items.Select(item => new SelectListItem
                                     {
                                         Text = text(item),
                                         Value = value(item),
                                         Selected = (selectedValue.ToString() == value(item))
                                     });
    }
```

Also, I was able to use this code with Html.DropDownListFor, which completely eliminated the need for magic strings:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ContractId, Model.Contracts.ToSelectList(x => x.Value, x => x.Disp, Model.ContractId))
```